# iFrame content lost after blind Effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, iframe

I have a iframe, inside a div which blinds and show a couple of tabs. The content of the iframe is set on runtime.

Whenever I activate the `toggle('blind')` event, the content of the iframe is lost. I'm logging the content of the iframe.

Seems this problem is only presented with `Blind`, `Scale` and `Fold`, while with `Transfer` there seems to be happening an exception not finding a top. Weird this is, I launch the event from console and works find (Transfer), but the click crashes.

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/CJLopez/47625/) the fiddle where I was able to reproduce the problem.

Using `fade` works just perfect and looks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is strange behavior. The iframe is destroyed somehow.
The same effect will work if you do this:

```
$("#ContenidoAgenda").animate({
      height: 'toggle'
   }, 300, 
   function() {}
);
```

instead of

```
$("#ContenidoAgenda").toggle('blind');
```

[here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/47625/1/)

Comment: Thanks, works wonders!

Didn't knew i could use toggle on height!