# Twitter timeline widget resets iframe content after jquery-ui toggle effect

Tags: jquery-ui, iframe, twitter, timeline

After googling and analyzing DOM, i found out:

- iframe dynamically replaces twitter's timeline a-link
- jquery-ui effects force iframe to reload content
- [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20292728/iframe-content-lost-after-blind-effect)

[sample at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VladyslavKurmaz/xadL7/1/)

html

```
click here to start toggle
<div id="panel">
<a id="twitter-widget" class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/search?    q=%23Globallogic" data-widget-id="418408420543184896">#Globallogic</a>
</div>
```

css

```
#panel {
    background:gray;
    width:640px;
    height:512px;
}
```

js

```
!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)    [0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
$( window ).mousedown(function() {
    $( "#panel" ).toggle( "slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000 );
});
```

Is it possible to configure jquery-ui to avoid iframe reload? and I'm appreciated for any other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to reload the twitter widget's content:

`twttr.widgets.load()`

Be sure to run it after the widget has initially loaded as it will throw up an error otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this issue and I resolved it by dynamically loading child elements to the panel
and ask twitter to load the widget. To do this , if below is you twitter div
then

```
  <div id="panel">
    <a id="twitter-widget" class="twitter-timeline"          href="https://twitter.com/search?q=%23Globallogic" 
     data-widget-id="418408420543184896">#Globallogic</a>
    </div>
```

Please place the below java script anywhere using the script tags.

```
           window.twttr = (function (d, s, id) {
           var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
           t = window.twttr || {};
           if (d.getElementById(id)) return t;
           js = d.createElement(s);
           js.id = id;
           js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
           fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
           t._e = [];
           t.ready = function (f) {
           t._e.push(f);
           };return t;
           }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));
```

Use setInterval() call the update function. In this function you can remove the existing twitter iframe ( created at the time of loading) , and replace it with your original  link. after this is done simply call  twttr.widgets.load() a standard event given by twitter

```
 $(function(){

    function updateStatus(){
      var $twitter = $("#panel");
      $twitter.append(" <a id='twitter-widget' 
     class='twitter-timeline' href='https://twitter.com/search?  
    q=%23Globallogic' data-widget-   id='418408420543184896'>#Globallogic</a>");
    twttr.widgets.load();
    };
    setInterval(function(){updateStatus()}, 1000);
    });
```

Tweets that have images may take some time to load.